# Change selection color of active element in a group

Tags: interface, 3d-view, theme

When I use groups it is really hard to recognize the active element by it's selection color.

[image]

In this example the middle is the active.

How can I change the active element selection color if it is in a group?

Answer (score 2):

Here I am 5 years later with the same question. IM currelntly using Blender 2.91 and eventhough I looked I wasnt able to find the option. **BUT** If you go into preferences and click on THEME, instead of searching for the specific place where the SELECTION color is (if there is any), just change the Theme entirely. I took "MAYA theme" and it works great. older selection is green and child selection becomes white. [image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The old blender version gave different selection color for grouped (no collections) objects and was even harder to distinguish active and not active selection. The new blender version does not use different color but you are right the default coloring is still not easy to distinguish for everyone. I check your answer for the older Blender version tomorrow.

Comment: Hi :). The active object color is in *Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > **Active Object*** https://i.imgur.com/FbFTbAq.png :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Image above.  By entering Edit Mode for the Mesh it is quite clear visually what is the current selection. You can type [A] to select or unselect all vertices. You can snap cursor to selected object vertices if you choose.  Familiar, Easy, not very exciting.

[image]

Image above. Expect to read facts you already know. The 3D View and Outliner Windows identify active and selected objects .. by textual name.  The display the name is enabled for the selected object, which would display all the time selected or not selected.  The display name is an easy tag which might be useful to you.

[image]

Image above. Display name enabled.

**Failed Search**

I looked in the user preferences window and see active color and group color. I do not see something such as active color dominates group color.